# Unable to delete record from database Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Since adding logging functionality to my Entity Framework project, I have been unable to delete any records from the table.

Here are the data classes for the objects which are added to the database, the user to the user table and the log to the logs table:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }  //unique database key and API key for user

    public ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; }

    public User() { }
}

public class Log
{
    [Key] 
    public int logID { get; set; }
    public string logString { get; set; }
    public string logDateTime { get; set; }
    public string userAPIKey { get; set; }
    public Log() { }       
}
```

Here is how logs are added to the table, as since adding logging I've been having the issue:

```
public void addLogToUserWithApiKey(string logMessage, string apiKey)
{
        Log newLog = new Log();
        newLog.logID = makeLogID();
        newLog.logString = logMessage;
        newLog.logDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
        newLog.userAPIKey = apiKey;

        using (var context = new UserContext())
        {
            User logUser = checkIfUserExistsWithApiKeyandReturnUser(apiKey);

            if (logUser.Logs == null)
            {
                logUser.Logs = new Collection<Log>();
            }

            logUser.Logs.Add(newLog);
            context.Logs.Add(newLog);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

And finally, this is the code to delete a record:

```
public void deleteUserFromDatabase(string mApiKey)  
{
        using (var context = new UserContext())
        {
            try
            {
                User userToDelete = checkIfUserExistsWithApiKeyandReturnUser(mApiKey);

                if (userToDelete != null) 
                {
                    context.Users.Attach(userToDelete);
                    context.Users.Remove(userToDelete);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
}
```

There were no exceptions being called when the delete method was like that however it still wasn't working.

I changed the delete method to this:

```
User userToDelete = checkIfUserExistsWithApiKeyandReturnUser(mApiKey);

if (userToDelete != null) 
{
    if (userToDelete.Logs != null) 
    { 
        userToDelete.Logs.ToList().ForEach(log => userToDelete.Logs.Remove(log)); 
    }

    context.Users.Attach(userToDelete);
    context.Users.Remove(userToDelete);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And I got this error message:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Logs_dbo.Users_User_ApiKey". The conflict occurred in database "SecuroteckWebApplication.Models.UserContext", table "dbo.Logs", column 'userAPIKey'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @Kell it doesn't seem to recognise that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete a `User`, you would have to delete all `Log` entries associated with that user first.

```
var apiKey = String.Empty; // The id of the user you want to delete

using (var context = new UserContext())
{
    User userToDelete = checkIfUserExistsWithApiKeyandReturnUser(apiKey);
    if (userToDelete != null)
    {
        var userLogs = context.Logs.Where(l => l.userAPIKey == apiKey);
        if (userLogs.Any())
        {
            context.Logs.RemoveRange(userLogs);
        }

        context.Users.Attach(userToDelete);
        context.Users.Remove(userToDelete);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is returned from SQL Server. As it says, you cannot delete the User because there are records from the `dbo.Logs` table which are related to the deleted user and there is a foreign key defined linking the `userAPIKey` column with this deleted User.

Seeing your entity code, I can't tell why the foreign key was created in the first place, if you are using Entity Framework Code First. If this is your case, probably you are falling in an Entity Framework convention rule.

Anyways, there are some ways to solve this.

**If you are using EF Code First**. Delete all the logs pointing to the deleted user or update them setting them to `NULL`, depending on how much you need to preserve the logs for a deleted user.

**EDIT**: As the OP is using Code First, then the relationship between `Log` and `User` is not completely defined. This is the proper entity code if a strong relationship is what is intended by the OP.

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }  //unique database key and API key for user

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; }

    public User() { }
}

public class Log
{
    [Key] 
    public int logID { get; set; }
    public string logString { get; set; }
    public string logDateTime { get; set; }
    public string userAPIKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("userAPIKey")
    public virtual User User {get; set; }
    public Log() { }
}
```

With the strong relationship, logs should be deleted or set to null before being able to the delete the user if cascade conventions are not configured.

Comment: I think there may be a problem when adding the logs. I have been stepping through where the log is added to the user, and it looks to be adding to the collection. However, when stepping through the delete method the user logs are always empty!

Comment: Are you using EF Code First or EF Database First? These kind of issues have pretty different approachs depending on this, so please tell us what you are actually using.

Comment: EF Code First  .

Comment: Look at the edit, probably you are running in an issue because some lacking definition. You should also consider if you want to keep the `Logs` after the `User` deletion, depending on your application might be the correct thing to do, but then, a relationship between `Log` and `User` might not be a good idea. You can remove the relationship and simply add an unrelated `Log` entity. Is not a good idea to define relationships in Entity Framework if a foreign key is not the way to go.